# I cannot connect postgresql schema.table with dplyr package

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql, dplyr

Im trying to connect postgres with dplyr functions

```
my_db <- src_postgres(dbname = 'mdb1252', user = "diego", password = "pass")
my_db
src:  postgres 9.2.5 [postgres@localhost:5432/mdb1252]
tbls: alf, alturas, asociad, atenmed, base, bfa_boys_p_exp, bfa_boys_z_exp,
  bfa_girls_p_exp, bfa_girls_z_exp, bres, c21200012012, c212000392011, c212000532011,
  c21200062012, c212006222012, c212007352012, c212012112013, c212012242012,
  c212012452012, c2222012242012, calles, cap, cap0110, casos_tbc_tr09, casos_tbctr09,
  casosvadela, catpo, cbcvl, cie09, cie10, cie103d, cie103dantigua, cie10c, cie9a,
  cie9mc, clasiarc, coalc, coddepto, codedades, codest, codlocaerbio, codprov, coheb,
  cohec, cohep, cohiv, coho09_20110909_m, coign, combl, comet, comp, comport, conev,
  conymad, copri, corci3cod, corci910, cores, corin, cotab, cutoi, cutto, def0307,......
```

but when I try to connect a tbl

```
my_tbl <- tbl(my_db, 'def0307')

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  no existe la relación «def0307»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "def0307" WHERE 0=1;
                      ^
)
```

I think the problem is a schema issue because sql should be:

```
 SELECT * FROM mortalidad.def0307
```

I made `my_tbl` <- `tbl(my_db, 'mortalidad.def0307');`

`my_tbl <- tbl(my_db, c('mortalidad','def0307'))` without a solution.

Im having a lot of fun working with dplyr Im from SQL but I wish resolve that and trying dplyr  skills.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I vaguely remember thinking about this. Does `tbl(my_db, sql('mortalidad.def0307'))` work?

Comment: Or maybe `tbl(my_db, ident('mortalidad.def0307'))`

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly. I tried with the options you refer me but the error continues. Now is with both options ....          Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «)»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM (mortalidad.def0307) AS "_W2" WHERE 0=1;
                                         ^
)

Comment: @hadley thinking about your answer I came up to write the full sentence `my_tbl = tbl(my_db, dplyr::sql('SELECT * FROM mortalidad.def0307'))` and there I could connect to the schema and table. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally dplyr has the solution to this problem thanks to the latest version 0.7 recently announced by Hadley Wickham. The DBI and dbplyr libraries greatly simplified the connection between dplyr and PostgreSQL.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), 
host = "database.rstudio.com",
user = "hadley",
password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))
tbl <- dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema('mortalidad','def0307'))
```

Comment: In case someone comes here, an alternate is that I had to include the schema in double quotes, so this variant worked for me: `tbl <- dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema('"mortalidad"','def0307'))`

Comment: Thanks @Diego. I wonder where the documentation for this topic lives?

Answer (score 9):

You might want this,

```
db=src_postgres(dbname = 'mdb1252',  
               user = "diego", password = "pass", options="-c search_path=mortalidad")
```

Comment: That works!. I would like just `my_tbl <- tbl(my_db, 'mortalidad.def0307')`. I think that @hadley is working in that enhancement. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

If anybody ends up here with the same problem, here is what works for me: (taken from @Diego's comment from Feb 6'14)

```
postgre_table <- function (src, schema, table) {
  paste('SELECT * FROM', paste(schema, table, sep = '.')) %>% 
    sql() %>% tbl(src = src)
}
```