# Select unique values with 'select' function in 'dplyr' library

Tags: r, select, unique, dplyr

Is it possible to select all *unique* values from a column of a `data.frame` using `select` function in `dplyr` library?
Something like "`SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM table1`" in `SQL` notation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

In dplyr 0.3 this can be easily achieved using the `distinct()` method.

Here is an example:

`distinct_df = df %>% distinct(field1)`

You can get a vector of the distinct values with:

`distinct_vector = distinct_df$field1`

You can also select a subset of columns at the same time as you perform the `distinct()` call, which can be cleaner to look at if you examine the data frame using head/tail/glimpse.:

`distinct_df = df %>% distinct(field1) %>% select(field1)
distinct_vector = distinct_df$field1`

Comment: This works if the data frame is already in R, but it doesn't work if you're trying to do the query directly on the database via a db connection (i.e. `src_postgres()`). It reports: `Error: Can't calculate distinct only on specified columns with SQL`

Comment: See this question for how to connect the src_postgres() and dplyr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592266/i-cannot-connect-postgresql-schema-table-with-dplyr-package

Comment: Note that the way `distinct()` works has changed in dplyr 0.5. By default `distinct()` now only returns the columns that are used as arguments to `distinct()`. If you want to retain the other columns you now have to pass `.keep_all = TRUE` as an additional argument to `distinct()`

Comment: Yep, dplyr 0.5 broke my code previously written using 0.3 and distinct. Why the change?  The previous default behavior was useful and the natural way to do it.

Answer (score 25):

Just to add to the other answers, if you would prefer to return a vector rather than a dataframe, you have the following options:

**dplyr >= 0.7.0**

Use the `pull` verb:

```
mtcars %>% distinct(cyl) %>% pull()
```

**dplyr < 0.7.0**

Enclose the dplyr functions in a parentheses and combine it with `$` syntax:

```
(mtcars %>% distinct(cyl))$cyl
```

Comment: I love that you identified `pull` as a verb -- more poetic (and descriptive) than "function"!

Answer (score 10):

The `dplyr` `select` function selects specific columns from a data frame. To return unique values in a particular column of data, you can use the `group_by` function. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(5)
dat = data.frame(x=sample(1:10,100, replace=TRUE))

# Return the distinct values of x
dat %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise() 

    x
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
```

If you want to change the column name you can add the following:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  select(unique.x=x)
```

This both selects column `x` from among all the columns in the data frame that `dplyr` returns (and of course there's only one column in this case) and changes its name to `unique.x`.

You can also get the unique values directly in base `R` with `unique(dat$x)`.

If you have multiple variables and want all unique combinations that appear in the data, you can generalize the above code as follows:

```
set.seed(5)
dat = data.frame(x=sample(1:10,100, replace=TRUE), 
                 y=sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace=TRUE))

dat %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  select(unique.x=x, unique.y=y)
```

Comment: Or use the new `distinct()` function in dplyr 0.3